# Consulta do Mongoose retorna um Array Vazio

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Estou estudando o mongoose e estou enfrentando um problema.

Ao tentar usar o find ele apenas retorna um vetor vazio enquanto deveria retornar todos do MongoDB.

Aqui está o código.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');



var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log("Conectado");
});

var usuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nome: String,
  senha: String
});

var Usuario = mongoose.model('usuario', usuarioSchema);

var us1 = new Usuario({nome:"sheldon",senha:"21456"});


db.collection('usuario').insertOne(us1);

Usuario.find(function(err,docs){
  console.dir(docs);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não está totalmente dito na documentação do Mongoose, então espero que sirva de luz para muita gente.

Ao criar um modelo usando a função `model()` "E" passando apenas dois parâmetros(o nome do model e o Schema) estamos dizendo para ele que o nome da Collection do Mongodb atrelada ao model é igual a:

```
Nome do Model com letra minuscula e um "s" no final.
```

Por isso sempre dava array vazio, não existia essa Collection no meu banco de dados.

**Como foi Resolvido?**

Você pode passar um terceiro parâmetro, esse parâmetro é opcional e diz o nome da Collection que o Model está atrelado.

**Resumidamente em dois casos:**

1- Apenas dois paramêtros no construtor do model.

```
var Usuario = mongoose.model('usuario', usuarioSchema);
```

Ele vai procurar a collection `usuarios`.

2 - Três parâmetros

```
var Usuario = mongoose.model('usuario', usuarioSchema,"usuario");
```

Ele vai procurar a collection `usuario`.